# Do you need to extract the time field in Splunk, or is that automatic?

Tags: splunk

I'm using the UI to insert some log data into Splunk. When I press "Extract Fields" in Splunk, I'm able to highlight the time field and enter in a name for that field, like "timestamp."

However, I've already specified the timestamp field in the source type. Does this mean I do not have to manually extract the timestamp field per event? In the "Extract Fields > Select Fields" UI, can I safely ignore and leave the timestamp field unhighlighted without a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splunk's Add Data and Extract Fields wizards are pretty good about extracting timestamps.  That said, it's considered Best Practice to specify `TIME_PREFIX`, `TIME_FORMAT`, and `MAX_TIMESTAMP_LOOKAHEAD` settings for every sourcetype.  It sounds like you've already done some of that so there's no need to do so in the UI.